# Make communicate a Thread and a Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, events, android-activity, observer-pattern

i would like to know if there is a way to make communicate a **Thread** and a **Activity**, the point is that the Thread **don't have to** know the Activity instance and the Activity **don't have to** know the Thread instance. The Thread generate some event with parameter that the UI have to collect.  In the beginning i thought about the Observer pattern, but you have to registrate the instance in the addObserver method.

Comment: `the point is that the Thread don't have to know the Activity instance and the Activity don't have to know the Thread instance.`  Why?

Comment: Becasue the UI communicate with the class VcAgent that offers all the method the he needs like call, hang, ecc (It is a voip app). This class when its initializzated, spawn a server thread to receive all the incoming connection and than, when a connection arrive, the Thread spawn an another thread to handle the connection. This last thread have send to the UI some message, changing the current layout or making it ring. So the only point of contact between the threads and the UI it is the VcAgent (that is Singleton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of decoupling both components would be to have them communicate through an event bus. If both the activity and the thread acquire an instance of the same bus, one component could post events to the bus, and the other register to receive them.

[Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) is a really good implementation of this pattern.

Comment: Excelent! Using it with the singleton its perfect for my situation!